# Terraform azurerm loop through files and content

Tags: azure, loops, terraform

With terraform (1.0.11), I want to create multiple resource groups in my azure subscription.

```
  resource "azurerm_resource_group" "resourcegroup" {
    name     = "rg-${var.client}-${var.env}"
    location = var.location
  }
```

But I want the values to be taken from files within a directory.

```
cat clients/client1.tfvars
client = "client1"
env    = "testing"

cat clients/client2.tfvars
client = "client2"
env    = "prod"
```

I want terraform to loop through these files and create one resource group per file using the values inside of it.

Is that even possible ? I tried playing around with fileset, file and locals but couldn't really have a result, as i'm kind of a newbie with terraform language.

```
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "resourcegroup" {
  for_each = fileset("${path.module}/resources", "*")
  name     = "rg-test-${each.value.client}-${each.value.env}"
  location = var.location
}
```

Obviously not working because i'm just looping through file names, and no the content.

Tried to build local with templatefile

```
locals {
allclients = templatefile("${path.module}/templates/env.tpl", { clients = fileset("${path.module}/resources", "*")})
}
```

```
cat templates/env.tpl
%{ for client in clients ~}
${client}= file("./resources/${client}")
%{ endfor ~}
```

In this case, the function file is ignored and consider a simple string, predictable i guess as it is not a .tf file.

Why I am not creating a variable with is a list of objects with all the clients ? Because eventually there will dozens and dozens clients and i think that managing files would be much more easier and human readable.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: "I tried playing around with fileset, file and locals" - can you show what you actually tried and explain why it does not work?

Comment: @Marcin edited my post to add what i tried